# easy way to map a range of numbers to a value in cpp

Tags: c++, enums, maps, unordered

Is there any way to map a range of numbers to a particular number or value in cpp like this:

1-10  : 15

10-20 : 05

the range would be consecutive numbers. the value could be any random number. there is no arithmetic calculation possible on range to derive the value. there is no such relation. I need a hard coded mapping.

Update:
I am familiar with maps. consider a map like the one below.

```
{
    {1,10}
    {2,10}
    {3,10}
    ...
    {10,10}
    {11,20}
    {12,20}
    ...
    {15,20}
    {16,30}
    {17,30}
    {18,30}
}
```

Instead of doing this for each number, i want to do it for range as value is same for consecutive numbers like below.

```
{
    {1 to 10  ,10}
    {11 to 15 ,20}
    {16 to 18 ,30}
}
```

Is there any way to do this.

I know one way to do this which is defining lower bound and upper bound in the array and comparing the input with them.

```
{
    {1,10,10},
    {11,15,20},
    {15,18,30}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for your problem. It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is the interval in the ranges always of size 10? Please provide more details and also show your own attempt(even if it's not working)!

Comment: Please show the work you've already written so far, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results. You have to show your work first, and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your task and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: What do you mean by "map a range"? What is the type of this range? Do you want to generate this range on-the-fly when needed or store it whole together with mapped number?

Comment: I think your problem is a XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is called `Interval Map`. There's no built-in data structure for that in C++ but you can make your own or use an existing implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a hard coded mapping.

If you can use boost, you can do something like following:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int, boost::hash<std::pair<int, int>>> myMap = {
    { { 1,  10} , 15 },
    { { 10, 20} , 5 },    

};
```

Otherwise you will have to provide a hash for `std::pair` :

```
// A trivial hash function used to hash a pair
struct hash_pair { 
    template <class T1, class T2> 
    size_t operator()(const pair<T1, T2>& p) const
    { 
        auto hash1 = hash<T1>{}(p.first); 
        auto hash2 = hash<T2>{}(p.second); 
        return hash1 ^ hash2; 
    } 
}; 

std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int, hash_pair> myMap = {
    { { 1,  10} , 15 },
    { { 10, 20} , 5 },    

};
```

[<kbd>`Demo Here`</kbd>](https://rextester.com/FNSQD1901)

Comment: The problem is when you add overlapping ranges, they won't merge.

Comment: @Rinat OP isn't clear if he wants to merge, given his edits to the original problem statement, btw which also didn't talk about merging. It was as simple as putting a hard coded table for lookup, etc.